# Fastest way to retrieve data from API

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, performance, api

I am using [this](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:Main) API to retrieve around 24.000 items from it.

So first I take the items list from [here](https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings) (Warning, slow browsers may crash).

Then I loop over all the items and find all the info for each item. Something like:

https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items/itemidhere

and the insert the info into MySQL database.

PD: real question starts after this line below.

---

Im trying to find the fastest way to get the info from those links and insert it. For this I am using:

-GSON library (easiest and fastest way to control JSON)
-HikariCP (for database connection pools)
-Threads (each thread takes care of 1000 items if there are 24 threads)

I did some tests and here are the results for collecting and inserting the 24.000 items:

-Threads: 50
-DB Pool size: 10
-Time: 644 seconds

-Threads: 100
-DB Pool size: 10
-Time: 607 seconds

-Threads: 250
-DB Pool size: 15
-Time: 662 seconds

-Threads: 500
-DB Pool size: 20
-Time: 689 seconds

I know the slowest thing here is the network.
My computer and internet arent that slow:
-300mb/s internet
[image]
-Intel 5820k
-16GB DDR4

So whats left may be the code implementation...

```
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb");
    config.setUsername("root");
    config.setPassword("none");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(depending on case);
    Core.ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

This is the setup for the database connection pool. I start the threads with a Cyclic barrier:

```
    final CyclicBarrier _threadGate = new CyclicBarrier(depends on case);
    ArrayList<Thread> _threadList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then

```
     _threadList.add(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    _threadGate.await();
                    //Parsing happens a bit later
```

Here I loop through all the list and get the info from the url (I skipped variable declaration):

```
                        _id = _itemList.get(i);
                        _stringUrl = "https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items/" + _id;
                        _responseText = new URL(_stringUrl);
                        _requestUrl = (HttpURLConnection) _responseText.openConnection();
                        _requestUrl.connect();
                        _requestStatus = _requestUrl.getResponseCode();
                        if(_requestStatus == 200){
                           _jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                            _rootElement = _jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) _requestUrl.getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                            _rootObject = _rootElement.getAsJsonObject();
```

And the from the `_rootObject` do a lot of parsing and checking if json exits etc etc... And at the end the insertion...

Here is how I start the threads after everything is processed in the main class:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < _threadList.size(); i++) {
        _threadList.get(i).start();
    }
```

INFO: [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing) about why didnt I use bigger pool size.

**What i DO NOT understand is:**
-why if there are more threads the result is slower
-I mean,cmon maybe the network is slow but, few requests could fill 300mb/s?
-would implementing a better code make this faster?

**I actually see it like this:**
-more threads -> slower internet, which makes pulling info slow.
-bigger pool size -> slower insertion due to many connections
-more threads and small connection pool -> inserts queued and stalled
-few threads and small connection pool -> slow pull info

**Updates**
-tried classic connection over pooled, 1 connection/pool and results are slower, like 30 seconds slower
-tried ExecutorService over CyclicBarrier, results slower by 10 seconds.

Comment: Are you closing the connections when you're done with them? Are you insterting the items one at a time, or as a batch? Batch would be the quicker way to insert them

Comment: More threads = More Taskswitches. So there is a "Peek" where more Threads make it worse. Some people suggest as a rule of thumb to not use more threads than CPU cores for one parallel task. Personally I don't know if this is reasonable always. Also I'd recommend an ExecutorService instead of ArrayList<Thread>

Comment: @Fildor tried this, with ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(some pools); but still the same results, in fact it may be slower by 5-10 seconds

Comment: I'd recommend filling your code with logs including timestamps. That way, you can see *exactly* where the bottlenecks are, whether its the downloading, or the inserting into the DB etc. Also, does the API have any rate limiting? It might detect that you are hitting it heavily and slow down your requests.

Comment: @SteveEdson yeah... it may be that, thanks for the help :D, tried a lot of things and I always end up slower, not faster rofl

Answer (score 0):

(Too many questions for a 'comment.)

I'm confused -- you are "retrieving data" and you are "inserting" it.  Which side should we focus on?  Which side do you have control over?

You are getting only 30-40 rows inserted per second?  That is pathetic.

Let's focus on how you are doing the `INSERTs` into the MySQL table.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- I need to see the Engine and indexes and other stuff.  Please provide some clues about the `INSERTs` -- One row at a time vs batched (10x improvement here)?  Sequential versus random `PRIMARY KEY`?  How big are the tables?  How big is the buffer_pool?  What version of MySQL (newer versions have some extra tricks)?

There is some contention between threads, so "too many" threads can actually slow down activity.  But I think that is a secondary issue.

What percent of the 306Mb/s is consumed?